# Using proto files as the one source for documentation - handling expanded metadata/comments

Tags: protocol-buffers, documentation, grpc

We currently use gRPC exclusively and generate our documentation from the proto files. I want one place (the protofile) to define all related documentation for a service, preferably with some reference structure to follow.

We have been including extra information as comments in the proto files, while this has been working it would be nice if there was some sort of structured metadata template we could leverage for this. For example, I want the proto files and documentation to contain expanded information about errors and error handling. It would be nice if there was some structure to adopt for this, rather than trying to define our own pattern in comments.

Curious to know what people in the community have been doing for their gRPC documentation? Do you just maintain extra documentation outside of the protofile, or do you inline it with comments?